# Multiple Similar Route not working in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have two routes, but of them are not working on the same time. The one which is on the top working fine but the bottom one not works

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "GetKeyWordSearch",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{keyword}/{Selection}"
                //defaults: new { selection = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );            
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
               name: "GetChapter",
               routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{bookName}/{chapterNum}/"
                //defaults: new {}
            );
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Is any quickly look into this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those 2 routes have the same pattern. There's absolutely no difference between them and the routing engine has no way of disambiguating them. And since routes are evaluated in the order in which they are defined, the first one is always picked.

In order to make this work you need to constrain the parameters using regular expressions or custom constraints. For example:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "GetKeyWordSearch",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{keyword}/{Selection}",
    constraints: new { keyword = @"[0-9]" },
    defaults: new { selection = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "GetChapter",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{bookName}/{chapterNum}"
    constraints: new { bookName = @"[a-z]" },
    defaults: new { chapterNum = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

In the example I provided, the `keyword` can only contain numbers whereas the `bookName` only letters. This way the routing engine will be able to disambiguate the between the following urls and dispatch them to the proper controller action:

```
api/somecontroller/someaction/123
api/somecontroller/someaction/foo
```

Obviously you will have to adapt the regular expressions to match your specific needs but remember that there must be some pattern that will make the difference.

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful and better explanation.